# How do I customize banner width on this free theme?

Tags: css, wordpress, slider, banner

Here's is the link to my client's site:

http://contentchilly.com/

I opened editor in Wordpress and found only one slider related PHP. I do not know PHP but have an idea. So I found this file named "tc_voila_slider.php" and found that it had 3 lines like :

```
 <img width="1170" height="500" src="<?php echo TC_BASE_URL ?>inc/img/colonnes.jpg" class="slide wp-post-image" alt="<?php _e( 'Create beautiful sliders','customizr') ?>">
```

In all three lines, I changed the width to 500 and height to 200, but it's not showing any change. How do I modify the widths and heights of my banner on slider? It's just stretching my banner images. Also I want to move the slider up a bit. There's a lot of space empty and below the sliders, there are 3 circles that I want to show users on home page so they don't have to scroll down. How do I get rid of extra spaces?

### Edit

Also, I put this code in style.css after inspecting the images in firebug; it's no use either.

```
.slide .wp-post-image {
  width=200px;
  height=200px;
}
```

Comment: Rather than using `=`, it's `:` (in css)

Comment: Try to modify `orange.css` `.carousel .item {
  line-height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 500px;
}`

Comment: ok..lemem try..thanks. I'll get back soon.

Comment: @kevinamadeus : I only see style.css. There's no orange.css in the WP editor

Comment: I added in style.css like this but no use: 
/* Include your own css below to override the theme stylesheet */
 
.carousel .item { line-height: 500px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 500px; }

Comment: @Farkie: I tried that..not working

Comment: line 6913 on `http://contentchilly.com/wp-content/themes/customizr/inc/css/orange.css?ver=2.0.5`. Well actually I do think you can override it in your style.css, but try to set those 500px to 200px to see the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In customizr you can add some custom css in `style.css`, just edit it and modify the slider with adding the lines below :

```
.carousel-image img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

This should works

### EDIT

To change the position of the slider you have to modify the `.carousel .item, reduce the` height` will make it higher in your page for ex.

To reduce the space between the slider and the 3 circles you can delete the `margin-top` instruciton in `#main-wrapper`.

As you probably know, it's pretty hard to answer to this type of question whithout having the whole graphic layout. CSS can be pretty hard to configure, especially when you got many parameters as here.

Comment: Thanks. Its working. However, I am unable to move the slider up and in center. Also, the transparent div overlapping the images is still of same size. It should be according to the images. Also, how do I remove extra space below the slider so that the three circles with images are visible on page load? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to set the Customizr slider's height to 250px. Change the value to your needs.

```
/* Adjust the Slider Height */
#customizr-slider.carousel .item {
height:         250px;
min-height:     250px;
line-height:    250px;
}
```

I would recommend to make your customizations either in the custom CSS section of the customizer option screen, or in the style.css file of a child theme (http://www.themesandco.com/snippet/creating-child-theme-customizr/).
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.